# css styling for .active link not working for single page using sections

Tags: html, css

I've been emailed a zip file of a template purchased from themeforest and they've asked me to modify it.
There's a horizontal nav bar that has a number of links on it to different sections on the page (it's a single page website), and in the [unmodified template](http://goudkamp.stacklaw.com.au/v2/template/index.html), the active nav link (whether it is Home, Team, Services or Contact) has a different background colour depending on which one you clicked.
When I use [my modified page](http://goudkamp.stacklaw.com.au/v2/index.html), the "active nav link" styling doesn't appear to work.

I can't figure out where it's going wrong.
It may be that I am not familiar with the various scripts or bootstrap css that are being linked into the page.

I have tried changing the name of the `.active` class to `.viewing` in case it's a pseudo/naming conflict and it doesn't make a difference.

The nav bar source is as follows:

```
<div class="span9 nav-wrapper">
                        <nav>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#section-home" id="nav-home" class="active">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#our-team" id="nav-team">Team</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#our-services" id="nav-services">Services</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contact-section" id="nav-contact">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                        <div class="header-phone-number"><span>Call us on</span> <i class="icon-phone"></i> 1800 25 1800</div>
                    </div>
```

and the CSS that applies to its links is:

```
nav a {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 26px 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
}

nav a:hover {
    background: #616a73;
}

nav a:hover, 
nav a:visited {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}

nav a.active {
    background: #4c5660 url(../img/banner-bg.jpg);
    color: #fff;
    outline: none;
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction of how the ".active" class works for this particular navigation bar and how it is applied to the other nav links when clicked?  Is it a jquery thing?
Why is my modified page "broken" when all I think I've changed from the template for this nav bar is the colours?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean it works fine here?
I've tried 3 different browsers and all have the same result.

Comment: I'm seeing the desired behavior on the site you linked to while using Linux Chrome 35.0.1916.153.

Comment: In your modified page, the link clicked on doesn't change the link to active.

Comment: On the template?  yeah it's working fine... but I can't see it working on http://goudkamp.stacklaw.com.au/v2/index.html.  If the "Team" button is clicked, it takes you to the correct section, but the nav button you clicked for "Team" should now be a lighter shade of grey (#4c5660).

Comment: "Works fine" means "Home" currently has a lighter blue background by default due to .active which is what you asked. If you want the "Team" link to have .active, you need to edit your post to ask THAT question as well as samples of what you have tried to get that behavior.

Comment: ok sorry - I may have presumed people knew what I meant.  I've updated my question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something wrong with the JQuery.

If the following bit runs the class of active works perfectly fine:

```
$('nav a').click(function(){
      $('nav a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      var href= $(this).attr('href');

      if ( guardianIsMobile === true ){
          $('.nav-wrapper').hide();
      }

      $.scrollTo( href, 800, {
          onAfter : function(){
              //add function to do after the animation here if required
          } ,
          offset: -30 //use this to position the window exactly where you want
      });

      return false;
   });
```

If you look at the console on your site you are getting this following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null
```

This error references custom.js line 148 which is:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("contact-map"),myMapOptions);
```

Maybe something with the map is goofing you up?

Comment: I think you're on the right track...
The map used on the template isn't shown on the index.html - so it must be defined in javascript somewhere.
In my effort to replace that map with my google map, I replaced the DIV that corresponded to it with one of my own and added the iframe.
This must've broken the custom.js.

I'll start here and see how I go.  Thanks

Comment: @ReeceDodds you might be able to remove that snippet from custom.js and it may work. Kind of hard to debug from my end, sorry =)

Comment: reverted back to using the same div id as the template, modified the google map settings in custom.js to suit.
All fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about adding classes without the use of javascript or php. If you are willing to use either, this is what I was able to come up with:

**jQuery**

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $("nav").find("a.current").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
});
```

**PHP** (not tested)

```
<?php
    $nav = "<nav><ul><li>";
    $links = array(
        '#home' => 'Home',
        '#serv' => 'Service',
        '#con' => 'Contact',
        '#about' => 'About'
    );

    if(isset($_GET['link'])) // link = integer
    {
        $i = 1;
        foreach($links as $key => $val)
        {
            if($_GET['link'] == $i)
            {
                $nav .= "<a class =\"current\" href=\"".$key."\">".$val."</a>";
            }
            else
            {
                $nav .= "<a href=\"".$key."\">".$val."</a>";
            }
            ++$i;
        }
    }

    echo $nav; // Somewhere
?>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/42m2U/1/)